# Running executables produced by F# 3 under Mono

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I would like to compile an executable using the F# 3.0 command-line compiler, and then run it under Mono.

The code starts to execute, but Mono dies almost immediately complaining it cannot load System.Core. Googling this suggests that I should be targeting .net 3.5, and not version 4. Further Googling suggests that the F# compiler used to take option --cli-version, but it no longer seems to accept that.

I am sure there is a way, seeing as if I were to use MSVC there would be somewhere I could click to set the desired CLR version.

What should I do please? Many thanks.

EDIT:

I have tried targeting .net 3.5 on a simpler project developed in the MSVC GUI. The executable then asked for FSharp.Core 2.0.0, and got further than before. The F# 3 compiler seems to come with a .net 2.0 core library, so I would expect that it is supposed to be able to generate code compatible with obsolete versions of the framework. The question this leaves is "if the GUI can do it, how do I do the same thing from the command line", please?

Comment: Digging through the source reveals this error message - does it help `"The command-line option '--cliroot' has been deprecated. Use an explicit reference to a specific copy of mscorlib.dll instead."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using F# 3.0 there's no reason not to use .NET 4.0 by default (unless, of course, you need to interoperate with existing .NET 2.0 or 3.5 assemblies).

Which version of Mono are you running on? F# 3.0 requires Mono 2.10 or newer, but I'd strongly suggest you use Mono 3.0 or newer.

Comment: I am using 2.10.8.1 (default on Ubuntu). The exception I get is "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version 4.0.0.0, Culture=....."

Comment: @JoeHuha If you're on Ubuntu 12.04 or newer, just uninstall mono, then clone/build/install it from the [sources on GitHub](https://github.com/mono/mono); then do the same for F# 3.0.

Comment: I could, however my aim really is to make it portable so it would run out-of-the-box and others could use it easily.

Comment: @JoeHuha Most people I know that are running F# on Mono are using Mono 3.0. If you really must use Mono 2.10.8, you should post this to the [fsharp-opensource](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fsharp-opensource) mailing list -- they can help you troubleshoot the issue, which could be an F# installation issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll probably try that once everything else has failed. I have updated the question to to explain that I want to crosscompile for an older version of .net, and that it seems possible from MSVC.